# Param gets passed into a React-Query function but its value is sometimes undefined - causing API to return 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query, tanstackreact-query

As 2 params are passed from the frontend to trigger the `GET` request in another TS file, one of the params seem to have unsuccessfully been passed due to unknown rerenders, thereby causing the API call to return 404 Error in the console.

[image: Rendering of the frontend after 1 page refresh]

When I try console-logging the params in the react query function alone, I found out that the params are rerendered up to 5 times.

[image: Console-logging the params from ReactQuery function]

Here is the code in the `movie-api.tsx` file that receives the params in the react query function. The console.log shows the rerenders, casuing the `RESULT_PAGE` to become 'undefined' and thereby causing the API to return 404 errors in the console log.

```
export const searchMovies = (QUERY?: string | undefined, RESULT_PAGE?: number | undefined) => {

    // This one seems to have no problem
    console.log('QUERY: ', QUERY)

    // This one has a lot of problem showing up, thus causing API to return 404
    console.log('RESULT_PAGE: ', RESULT_PAGE)

    const APINAME = 'search'
    const APIURL = `${BASEURL}/${APINAME}/${CINEMA_TYPE}${APIKEY}&query=${QUERY}&page=${RESULT_PAGE}`

    return useQuery({
        queryKey: [QUERY, RESULT_PAGE],
        queryFn: async () => {
            const response = await axios.get(APIURL)
            const data: unknown = await response.data
            return data as MovieData
        },
        enabled: QUERY !== undefined && QUERY !== ''
    })
}
```

https://github.com/iceyisaak/cineverse/blob/main/src/api/movie-api.tsx#L147

---

Meanwhile, the code on the `SearchPage.tsx` seems to work without problem. Here is what gets rendered when console-logging variables in this frontend file alone.

[image: Rendering the frontend varables seem to have no problem]

```
export function SearchPage() {

    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams()
    const searchParamsString = searchParams.get('query')?.toString()


    // These 2 always show up as expected in the console.log()
    console.log('currentPage: ', currentPage) 
    console.log('searchParamsString: ', searchParamsString)


    // This is where the 2 varables get sent to the query function in movie-api.tsx
    const { data: SearchMoviesData } = searchMovies(searchParamsString, currentPage)


    const nextPageHandler = () => {
        if (currentPage === SearchMoviesData?.total_pages) return
        setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)
    }

    const lastPageHandler = () => {
        setCurrentPage(SearchMoviesData?.total_pages!)
    }

    const firstPageHandler = () => {
        setCurrentPage(1)
    }

    const prevPageHandler = () => {
        if (currentPage === 1) return
        setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)
    }

    // Causing 1 extra rerender on the frontend: Seems to NOT be the cause of the issue
    useEffect(() => {
        updateResultPageQuery()
    }, [currentPage])


    const updateResultPageQuery = () => {
        searchParams.set("page", currentPage.toString())
        setSearchParams(searchParams)
    }

return (
   // FRONTEND TSX 
)}
```

https://github.com/iceyisaak/cineverse/blob/main/src/pages/search-page/search-page.tsx#L20

My Questions:

1. What causes the `RESULT_PAGE` to not be properly passed and become `undefined`? How do I ensure that it will always have a value?
2. Why is the React Query function rerendering up to 5 times? I'd be happy to know what triggers this many rerenders in a single refresh of a page.

Looking forward to your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Since your query is dependant on `RESULT_PAGE`, add `RESULT_PAGE` to the `enabled` prop condition also, in your `searchMovies` hook:

```js
enabled: QUERY !== undefined && QUERY !== '' && RESULT_PAGE !== undefined
```

Otherwise, don't include it in the `APIURL` if it is `undefined`:

```js
const APIURL = `${BASEURL}/${APINAME}/${CINEMA_TYPE}${APIKEY}&query=${QUERY}${RESULT_PAGE !== undefined ? `&page=${RESULT_PAGE}` : ''}`
```

Btw it is a convention to name hooks with the prefix *use*, so `searchMovies` would become `useSearchMovies`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Would it be possible to make `RESULT_PAGE` to never be `undefined` at all in this case?

Comment: @iceyisaak sure, inside of the params of your hook, instead of having `RESULT_PAGE?: number | undefined` you can define it like this: `export const searchMovies = (QUERY?: string | undefined, RESULT_PAGE = 0)`. This way, `RESULT_PAGE` will evaluate to `0` when it's supposed to be `undefined`